# How to made Signup and Login Post Request on same Webpage

Tags: node.js, post

I am new in Nodejs and developing a login and signup page. But the thing which is different is I want my login and signup on same post request [image: SignUp]

and Login Page is
[image]

What I next do is in both form I add my action to home page but inside

```
app.post("/",function(req,res){
   
    

    
});
```

How will I differentiate between request is sign in or signup.. I want to do on same page and also I did not want to change my Url on browser while doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id recommend separate paths for both, but if still you want to achieve this with single request path. Then you need to add an identifier to differentiate between signup / signin requests.

you can pass it in body of POST request :

```
{
   username: xyz,
   password: abc,
   reqType: 'login'
}
```

Once you receive this body at you server, you can just simply check the value of req.body.reqType variable and perform the logic.

You can also pass the unique identifier to differentiate between signup / signin requests as a request header. At server side you can just check for req.headere.reqType and perform the desired actions,